# How to handle java.net.UnknownHostException while using retrofit

Tags: android, android-internet

I'm using retrofit to get and post data from the server. However, if my phone loses internet connection in middle of the app then I see error like this:

```
05-10 08:12:05.559  29369-29400/? D/Retrofit﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "my.server.com": No address associated with hostname
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
```

I would like to handle this error gracefully. I would like to catch the exception and show a toast message like "No internet connection".

I'm trying code like this but I get an error that: `java.net.UnknownHostException is never thrown in the try block`

```
  try {
      isTokenValid = MyManager.INSTANCE.getService().validate();
  }
  catch (RetrofitError cause) {
      Response r = cause.getResponse();

      if (r != null && r.getStatus() == 403) {
           isTokenValid = false;
      }
  }
  catch (UnknownHostException exception) {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to have a retrofit exception in the catch.

```
catch (RetrofitError error) {
    methodToDeterminErrorType(error);
}
```

The `RetroFitError` is a generic runtime exception. Once it hits the catch block you can actually verify what kind of a error was actually thrown by retrofit. Retrofit has a method `isNetworkError()` which is what you are probably looking for. 
So you can basically do something like this:

```
methodToDetermineErrorType(RetroFitError error) {
if (error.isNetworkType()) {
    // show a toast
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right now, error.isNetworkType() is deprecated. Just use error.getKind() == Kind.NETWORK